# Mostrar tabla de mysql en php,javascrip

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Tengo la siguiente base de datos,si es necesario usar javascrip no importa, pero que quede,es importante decir que uso ajax y json.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero solo puedo mostrar el ultimo registro
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ya que estoy utilizando ajax y json
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
este es mi codigo en php

```
    <?php

include("buscarCuenta.php");

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//
//                                                                                            //
//          Funcion que carga desde la lista de pendiente la solicitud generada               //
//          clases listaPendientesEjecutivo                                                   //
//                                                                                            //
//          0-temporal                                                                        //
//          1-cancelado                                                                       //
//          2-pendiente cartera                                                               //
//          3-tranmision                                                                      //
//          4-rechazado                                                                       //
//          5-pendiente ejecutivo                                                             //
//          6-aprovado                                                                        //
//          7-expirado                                                                        //
//                                                                                            //
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//


function listaPendientesEjecutivo()
{
  $sql="SELECT * FROM mtc.datosejecutivo;";

  $resultado=EjecutaProcedures($sql);
//print_r($res);



  while($row= mysqli_fetch_array($resultado))  
    {

      $num_folio=$row['num_folio'];
      $num_credito=$row['num_credito'];
      $nombreCliente=$row['nombreCliente'];
          $tasaAnterior=$row['tasaAnterior'];
      $tasaNueva=$row['tasaNueva'];
      if($tasaNueva<=0)
        $tasaNueva="No aplica";
          $spreadAnterior=$row['spreadAnterior'];
      $spreadNuevo=$row['spreadNuevo'];
       if($spreadNuevo<=0)
        $spreadNuevo="No aplica";

          $saldosNoDispuestosAnt=$row['saldosNoDispuestosAnt'];
      $saldosNoDispuestosNu=$row['saldosNoDispuestosNu'];
       if($saldosNoDispuestosNu<=0)
        $saldosNoDispuestosNu="No aplica";


          $comisionAperturaAnt=$row['comisionAperturaAnt'];

      $comisionAperturaNu=$row['comisionAperturaNu'];
      if($comisionAperturaNu<=0)
        $comisionAperturaNu="No aplica";


    }


$html='

<div class="col-md-10">

  <table id="pendientes" class="col-md-12 table table-bordered">
    <thead id="ctabla">
      <tr style="background-color:#EC0000;color:white;">
        <th class="col-md-1">Numero De Folio</th>
        <th class="col-md-1">Numero De Credito</th>
        <th class="col-md-1">Nombre Cliente</th>
        <th class="col-md-1">Tasa Anterior</th>
        <th class="col-md-1">Tasa Nueva</th>
         <th class="col-md-1">Spread Anterior</th>
         <th class="col-md-1">Spread Nuevo</th>
          <th class="col-md-1">Saldos No Dispuestos Anterior</th>
          <th class="col-md-1">Saldos No Dispuestos Nuevo</th>
          <th class="col-md-1">Comision Apertura Anterior</th>
          <th class="col-md-1">Comision Apertura  Nuevo</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="filas">

         <td COLSPAN="1">
        <p style="font-size:15px; text-align: center;">'.$num_folio.'</p></td>
          <td COLSPAN="1">
        <p style="font-size:15px; text-align: center;">'.$num_credito.'</p></td>
         <td COLSPAN="1">
        <p style="font-size:15px; text-align: center;">'.$nombreCliente.'</p></td>
        <td COLSPAN="1">
        <p style="font-size:15px; text-align: center;">'.$tasaAnterior.'</p></td>
        <td COLSPAN="1">
        <p style="font-size:15px; text-align: center;">'.$tasaNueva.'</p></td>
          <td COLSPAN="1">
        <p style="font-size:15px; text-align: center;">'.$spreadAnterior.'</p></td>
        <td COLSPAN="1">
        <p style="font-size:15px; text-align: center;">'.$spreadNuevo.'</p></td>
          <td COLSPAN="1">
        <p style="font-size:15px; text-align: center;">'.$saldosNoDispuestosAnt.'</p></td>
        <td COLSPAN="1">
        <p style="font-size:15px; text-align: center;">'.$saldosNoDispuestosNu.'</p></td>
          <td COLSPAN="1">
        <p style="font-size:15px; text-align: center;">'.$comisionAperturaAnt.'</p></td>
        <td COLSPAN="1">
        <p style="font-size:15px; text-align: center;">'.$comisionAperturaNu.'</p></td>
    </tbody>
  </table>

</div>


  ';


$paquete=array($html);
return json_encode($paquete);
}


?>
```

Comment: brother lo que sucede es que dentro del ciclo, recorres todo y las variables quedan con el ultimo valor, por enden cuando envias `html` solo queda con las ultimas variables, debes meter esa tambien dentro del ciclo, voy a generarte una respuesta de acuerdo a tu codigo

Comment: evita poner imágenes de código, es preferible que copies y pegues el código, lo selecciones y le des control + K para que tenga formato. De esta manera, facilitas a quienes deseas reproducir tu escenario. Saludos :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debes someter al la variable `$html` y la parte del body al ciclo para que agregue todas las variables y las etiquetas asi...

```
<?php 

include("buscarCuenta.php");

function listaPendientesEjecutivo()
{
  $sql="SELECT * FROM mtc.datosejecutivo;";

  $resultado=EjecutaProcedures($sql);
//print_r($res);
//creamos la cabecera de la tabla que solo se debe hacer una vez
    $html='

    <div class="col-md-10">

      <table id="pendientes" class="col-md-12 table table-bordered">
        <thead id="ctabla">
          <tr style="background-color:#EC0000;color:white;">
            <th class="col-md-1">Numero De Folio</th>
            <th class="col-md-1">Numero De Credito</th>
            <th class="col-md-1">Nombre Cliente</th>
            <th class="col-md-1">Tasa Anterior</th>
            <th class="col-md-1">Tasa Nueva</th>
             <th class="col-md-1">Spread Anterior</th>
             <th class="col-md-1">Spread Nuevo</th>
              <th class="col-md-1">Saldos No Dispuestos Anterior</th>
              <th class="col-md-1">Saldos No Dispuestos Nuevo</th>
              <th class="col-md-1">Comision Apertura Anterior</th>
              <th class="col-md-1">Comision Apertura  Nuevo</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="filas">';

  while($row= mysqli_fetch_array($resultado))  
    {

      $num_folio=$row['num_folio'];
      $num_credito=$row['num_credito'];
      $nombreCliente=$row['nombreCliente'];
      $tasaAnterior=$row['tasaAnterior'];
      $tasaNueva=$row['tasaNueva'];

      if($tasaNueva<=0){
            $tasaNueva="No aplica";
            $spreadAnterior=$row['spreadAnterior'];
            $spreadNuevo=$row['spreadNuevo'];
        }
       if($spreadNuevo<=0){
            $spreadNuevo="No aplica";
            $saldosNoDispuestosAnt=$row['saldosNoDispuestosAnt'];
            $saldosNoDispuestosNu=$row['saldosNoDispuestosNu'];
        }
       if($saldosNoDispuestosNu<=0){
            $saldosNoDispuestosNu="No aplica";
            $comisionAperturaAnt=$row['comisionAperturaAnt'];
            $comisionAperturaNu=$row['comisionAperturaNu'];
        }
      if($comisionAperturaNu<=0){
            $comisionAperturaNu="No aplica";
        }


//por cada registro el ciclo agregara una vez lo que tenga y lo ira concatenando con lo que ya tiene $html
        $html.='
                <td COLSPAN="1">
                <p style="font-size:15px; text-align: center;">'.$num_folio.'</p></td>
                  <td COLSPAN="1">
                <p style="font-size:15px; text-align: center;">'.$num_credito.'</p></td>
                 <td COLSPAN="1">
                <p style="font-size:15px; text-align: center;">'.$nombreCliente.'</p></td>
                <td COLSPAN="1">
                <p style="font-size:15px; text-align: center;">'.$tasaAnterior.'</p></td>
                <td COLSPAN="1">
                <p style="font-size:15px; text-align: center;">'.$tasaNueva.'</p></td>
                  <td COLSPAN="1">
                <p style="font-size:15px; text-align: center;">'.$spreadAnterior.'</p></td>
                <td COLSPAN="1">
                <p style="font-size:15px; text-align: center;">'.$spreadNuevo.'</p></td>
                  <td COLSPAN="1">
                <p style="font-size:15px; text-align: center;">'.$saldosNoDispuestosAnt.'</p></td>
                <td COLSPAN="1">
                <p style="font-size:15px; text-align: center;">'.$saldosNoDispuestosNu.'</p></td>
                  <td COLSPAN="1">
                <p style="font-size:15px; text-align: center;">'.$comisionAperturaAnt.'</p></td>
                <td COLSPAN="1">
                <p style="font-size:15px; text-align: center;">'.$comisionAperturaNu.'</p></td>';

    }
//cerramos la tabla que tam bien se debe hacer una vez la cual adentro del $html ya trae los registros
    $html.='
        </tbody>
      </table>

    </div>';


$paquete=array($html);
return json_encode($paquete);
}


?>
```

**NOTA:** cabe aclarar que no toque la logica de tu ciclo...

espero te sirva y la marques como resuleta XD... ReNiceCode...

Comment: muchas gracias amigo :)

Comment: De nada mi Bro, si te sirvio, marcala como aceptada, para que las futuras generaciones que vengan en busca de la misma respuesta la encuentren... ReNiceCode...